# Replacing a “time” column with values in minutes since time "0"

Tags: perl, shell, awk

I think it won't be a straightforward thing to solve, but here it is. I have a file in the following format:

```
"2004-04-19 12:25:00" 44 44
"2004-04-19 12:26:30" 36 36
"2004-04-19 12:27:15" 34 34
```

and I need a file with exact same content, except that the first row of the first column is 0, and remaining values of the first column are times in minutes since time 0 (since first time). Times should be rounded 3 digit after decimal (dot), like this:

```
0.000 44 44
1.500 36 36
2.250 34 34
```

Comment: Did you try doing anything? What is the specifc problem (to read the input file, compute the difference between the time strings, ...)?

Comment: What timezone are these times in?

Comment: @ysth What difference does that make?

Comment: I am writing a php script to do it, but didn't solve it yet

Comment: try this, `awk -F '[ :]' '{gsub("\"",""); if(NR==1){hour0=$2; min0=$3; sec0=$4} printf "%.3f" OFS "%s" OFS "%s\n",(($2-hour0)*3600+($3-min0)*60+($4-sec0))/60,$5,$6}' file` ...... This is your first post

Comment: It is only valid if the hours are recorded on the same day

Comment: thanks Jose...there are different days however...

Comment: @Haos chansen' solution is better in this case

Comment: @melpomene: if the times aren't UTC and they span a daylight savings change, you need to take that into account (and some times may be ambiguous ).  Even if they are UTC, that can affect the answer (e.g. the 'Z' in chansen's answer)

Answer (score 4):

I am as disappointed as the others who downvoted your question with your reluctance to even attempt to do this for yourself before asking for free help. If you always do this then you will never learn the language and will always have to rely on other people to do it for you. However, I would prefer that you got your solution from Stack Overflow, as I am sure you will only go elsewhere and ask the same question

This will do as you ask. It expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, and sends the output to `STDOUT`

To write the output to a file you would redirect it on the command line, like this

```
$perl fractional_minutes.pl mydata.txt > mydata_new.txt
```

and if you want to write back to the same file then you will need to use Perl's *in-place* option, like this

```
$perl -i.bak fractional_minutes.pl mydata.txt
```

which will save the old file as `mydata.txt.bak`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds qw/ ONE_MINUTE /;

my $t0;

while ( <> ) {

    s{^"([^"]*)"}{
        my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
        $t0 = $t if not defined $t0;
        sprintf('%.3f', ($t - $t0) / ONE_MINUTE);
    }e;

    print;
}
```

#### output

```
0.000 44 44
1.500 36 36
2.250 34 34
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for mktime() and gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\"" }
{ mins=mktime(gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",$2)) / 60 }
NR==1 { startMins=mins }
{ printf "%.3f%s\n", (mins-startMins), $3 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
0.000 44 44
1.500 36 36
2.250 34 34
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Moment;

my @times = map {
   Time::Moment->from_string($_ . 'Z', lenient => 1) 
} ('2004-04-19 12:25:00',
   '2004-04-19 12:26:30',
   '2004-04-19 12:27:15');

my $first = $times[0];
foreach my $time (@times) {
    printf "%.3f\n", ($time->rd - $first->rd) / (1/60/24);
}
```

Output:

```
0.000
1.500
2.250
```

Comment: my original file is very large...it would be hard to copy all the values into the perl script as you suggested...but thanks a lot for trying to help..

Comment: @Haos Then I suppose you should leave the file where it's at and read from it instead, right?

Comment: @Haos see the first comment to your question.  Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.  We're here to help you with specific questions about how you should write the code, so a single question should ask about reading the file *or* parsing the lines *or* calculating the time differences.  Since you didn't address the comment, this answer is perfectly correct in picking the most likely thing you might be having trouble with.

Comment: @Haos: This is clearly an example to show you how to do the complicated bit (the conversion of the dates). Hard-coding the input dates in the example code is the simplest way to demonstrate that. I'd hope it would be obvious that you should replace that section of the example with code that reads the data from the file. Perhaps I also need to reiterate what others have said - StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service.